# View is displaying "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies..." instead of actual Child data

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, displayfor

I have a master/child relationship model that I generated via a database-first import. When I try and output the child data on the same page, I get "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies..." strings displayed for each child row instead of the data. I thought .NET MVC was smart enough to recognize the child collection and auto-output the row data (I would eventually add display/edit formatted templates). I am able to iterate through data via a loop in the main view, so the data is in the collection, but attempting to DisplayFor the child class is displaying proxy names or something instead. Anyone know what's up? Thanks.

The generated model (extra fields left out for brevity) is as follows:

```
namespace Test.Models
{

    public partial class HCCB_CR
    {
        public HCCB_CR()
        {
            this.HCCB_CR_CONTACTS = new HashSet<HCCB_CR_CONTACT>();
        }

        public string CCID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<HCCB_CR_CONTACT> HCCB_CR_CONTACTS { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Test.Models
{
    public partial class HCCB_CR_CONTACT
    {
        public decimal ID { get; set; }     //key
        public string CCID { get; set; }    // foreign key to hccb_cr

        public virtual HCCB_CR HCCB_CR { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Generated scaffolding for Details (abbreviated):

```
@model Test.Models.HCCB_CR
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>HCCB_CR</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CCID)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CCID)
    </div>

    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HCCB_CR_CONTACTS)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Output:

```
CCID 
HCCB-CR100290 
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCB_CR_585E5CAF66461CDD0DF7F83DACDFCA848E78470297E638B38AB0FFDC8CBD83DASystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCB_CR_585E5CAF66461CDD0DF7F83DACDFCA848E78470297E638B38AB0FFDC8CBD83DASystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCB_CR_585E5CAF66461CDD0DF7F83DACDFCA848E78470297E638B38AB0FFDC8CBD83DASystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCB_CR_585E5CAF66461CDD0DF7F83DACDFCA848E78470297E638B38AB0FFDC8CBD83DASystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCB_CR_585E5CAF66461CDD0DF7F83DACDFCA848E78470297E638B38AB0FFDC8CBD83DASystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCB_CR_585E5CAF66461CDD0DF7F83DACDFCA848E78470297E638B38AB0FFDC8CBD83DA
```

What is System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCB_CR_... and why am I getting?

**UPDATE:** Hoping this may help. Debug output when I step into DisplayFor:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x3e70) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Step into: Stepping over non-user     code 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR>.Html.get'
The thread '<No Name>' (0x3e48) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACTS.get'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCBJEFF_CR_9D376C551350D68ED0D45F44495C7047639AE18E195454A7CE1DAB8EB66DDAF2.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACTS.get'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR.CCID.get'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.CreateSourceQuery<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.ValidateLoad<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>.Load'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT_0D5EDED0A9ECB95525658A667586E43649A2EDCBFD933981026D54A30B929661.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT_0D5EDED0A9ECB95525658A667586E43649A2EDCBFD933981026D54A30B929661'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT.CONTACTID.set'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT.CNAME.set'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT.CCID.set'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT.CONTACTID.get'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.CheckKeyMatchesEntity'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT.CNAME.get'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.TakeSnapshot'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT.CCID.get'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.TakeSnapshot'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT.HCCBJEFF_CR.get'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT_0D5EDED0A9ECB95525658A667586E43649A2EDCBFD933981026D54A30B929661.GetBasePropertyValue'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.TryGetBasePropertyValue'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.CreateBaseGetter.AnonymousMethod__4'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.Internal.PocoPropertyAccessorStrategy.GetNavigationPropertyValue'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.WillNotRefSteal'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupEntityReferenceToPrincipal'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT.HCCBJEFF_CR.set'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT_0D5EDED0A9ECB95525658A667586E43649A2EDCBFD933981026D54A30B929661.HCCBJEFF_CR.set'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.Internal.PocoPropertyAccessorStrategy.SetNavigationPropertyValue'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR>.ReferenceValue.set'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.SetEntityKey'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupEntityReferenceToPrincipal'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>.ReadNextElement'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Merge<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>.Load'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty<System.__Canon>'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.HCCBJEFF_CR_9D376C551350D68ED0D45F44495C7047639AE18E195454A7CE1DAB8EB66DDAF2.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACTS.get'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>>.AnonymousMethod__2'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata.Model.get'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Test2.Models.HCCBJEFF_CR_CONTACT>>'
```

HCCB_CR_CONTACT template:

```
    @model Test.Models.HCCB_CR_CONTACT

    <fieldset>
        <legend>HCCB_CR_CONTACT</legend>

        <div class="display-label">
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CCID)
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CCID)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
```

Comment: Are those the real class names?

Comment: HCCB_CR and HCCB_CR_CONTACT are the real class names that were generated from existing Oracle tables. The output seems to be displaying a generated proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Since it doesnt know how to render the items in the hashset, DisplayFor is calling the ToString method of each item in the set.

You may want to look at [creating MVC display templates and edit templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I tried a MVC display template and got the same output. Seemed like it was being ignored so I even explicitely specified the template name as the second parameter in the DisplayFor and still got that proxy output. It's odd though, because while debugging the DisplayFor, the debugger reports model.HCCB_CR_CONTACTS as the correct type and I can see the child data inside as I drill-down.

Comment: Did you create a template for the hashset or for the individual contact? The contact is what it doesn't know how to render. Here's something to try, in your view above, create a for each loop that loops through Model.Hccb_cr_contacts, rendering individual contact objects. If that works, you could move it into a template

Comment: I created a template for the individual contact called HCCB_CR_CONTACT. From what I've read, if I use an individual template (as oppossed to IEnumerable with loop), the DisplayFor should take care of the looping for me. I also tried a partial view called HCCB_CR_CONTACTS with the IEnumerable and a loop and am able to display the data fine. So the major issue I'm having, is why doesn't it directly render with (or without) template? In a debug breakpoint on the DisplayFor it knows it's passing contact type and lets me drill into the child data,but when it renders it spits out that proxies stuff.

Comment: FYI -Added debug output for DisplayFor in original post above.

Comment: You need to start more brute force, then template it later. For now, Forget the template, forget the partial view, just render the contacts manually. @foreach(hccb_cr_contact c in Model.hccb_cr_contacts) { @c.firstname } - I hope you see what I mean

Comment: It's just hard to forget templates when I keep reading that it's the recommended way to auto-loop through child records. I guess it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: I'm not saying to abandon it, I'm just saying that sometimes you need to start with the simplest, and once that's working, refactor it into templates. If I've answered your question, please don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I didn't make myself clear. I had it working from the beginning with a loop. My question is how to get working with a single DisplayFor with the child collection like recommended in various posts.

Comment: Can you show the template you set up for the displayfor of the hashaet?

Comment: Added templete above. Keep in mind, I shouldn't need a template for DisplayFor should do it's own formatting based on the child model datatypes.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but in your template, the name of the class is all light blue, except HCCB_CR_CONTACT, which I think means that razor cannot find your class.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/18/collections-and-asp-net-mvc-templated-helpers-displayfor-editorfor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but somehow, my **.cshtml** file (in **DisplayTemplates**) was not published (anymore).

Make sure it's **Build Action** is set to **Content**.

Took me hours to figure out, so I would like to mention it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself.  Make sure you have the following:

1. In your Shared views folder, you need a folder title DisplayTemplates.
2. In your DisplayTemplates folder you need your partial view, which is named exactly as your model (so in your case, the file would be /Shared/DisplayTemplates/HCCB_CR_CONTACT.cshtml, no underscore before the file name).

So as an example using your test stuff you would do something very similar to...

**/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/HCCB_CR_CONTACT.cshtml**

```
@model Test.Models.HCCB_CR_CONTACT

<fieldset>
    <legend>HCCB_CR_CONTACT</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
    </div>
    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CCID)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CCID)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

**/Views/HCCB_CR_BlahBlah.cshtml**

```
@model HCCB_CR

<div>
   <span>@Model.CCID</span>
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HCCB_CR_CONTACTS)       
</div>
```

***Note***:  This method uses ASP.Net MVC 5 and .Net 4.5.1 with razor views.